# getting an error using group by with where clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to fetch a list of salesmen with following details
EmpId, Salesman who got rating A for consecutive 3 year.

I've written the following query but getting an error.

```
SELECT salesman, empid
FROM Sales_temp
where rating = 'A'
AND(select max(year), min(year) from Sales_temp 
 having (max(year)-min(year) = 3))
AND Count(year)=3
```

To filter data of 3 consecutive years for 'A' rating I have used the following logic:

difference of max(year) for A rating minus min(year) for A rating = 3
and count(year)=3. However, I'm getting an error:

> scalar sub query can't have more than one column

please suggest.

Comment: I've removed groupby so please ignore heading and respond to my question.

Comment: please update you question if you have any update on that, commenting does not helps.

Comment: 'for consecutive 3 year.' is that for this year going back 3 years or is it any 3 consecutive years in history? Sample data would be nice.

Comment: A ddl sample also would be helpful along with the above points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
If you are interested in the years A was achieved

 drop table if exists sales_temp;
create table sales_temp(salesman int,empid int, rating varchar(1),year int);

insert into sales_temp values
(1,1,'a',2018),(1,1,'a',2017),(1,1,'a',2016),(1,1,'a',2015),
(2,2,'a',2018),(2,2,'a',2017),
(3,3,'b',2018),(3,3,'a',2017),(3,3,'a',2016),(3,3,'a',2015);

select salesman,empid,r1,r2,r3
from
(
select s.salesman,s.empid,year r1,
        (select year from sales_temp s1 where s1.salesman = s.salesman and s1.empid = s.empid and s1.year = s.year -1 and rating = 'a') r2,
        (select year from sales_temp s1 where s1.salesman = s.salesman and s1.empid = s.empid and s1.year = s.year -2 and rating = 'a') r3
 from sales_temp s
 where s.rating = 'a'
) s
where s.r1 is not null and s.r2 is not null and s.r3 is not null ;

+----------+-------+------+------+------+
| salesman | empid | r1   | r2   | r3   |
+----------+-------+------+------+------+
|        1 |     1 | 2018 | 2017 | 2016 |
|        1 |     1 | 2017 | 2016 | 2015 |
|        3 |     3 | 2017 | 2016 | 2015 |
+----------+-------+------+------+------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: @Salmon: Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The only way I think of to do this in MySQL would be to self join your table twice, and then aggregate by salesman.  Then, assert whether or not a salesman has at least one record with three consecutive A ratings:

```
SELECT
    s1.salesman, s1.empid
FROM Sales_temp s1
INNER JOIN Sales_temp s2
    ON s1.empid = s2.empid AND s2.year = s1.year + 1
INNER JOIN Sales_temp s3
    ON s2.empid = s3.empid AND s3.year = s2.year + 1
GROUP BY
    s1.salesman, s1.empid
HAVING
    SUM(CASE WHEN s1.rating = 'A' AND s2.rating = 'A' AND s3.rating = 'A'
             THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0;
```

### Demo

The intermediate joined table would be quite ugly, but it suffices to say that it gives each record in `Sales_temp` a chance to pair up with the next year, and then the year after that.  If a triplet can happen, and all three ratings are `A` quality, then that salesman would appear in the result set.

Comment: Question - the GROUP BY happens before the HAVING.  For a case with consecutive 'A, B, A, A, A' How do you know that the group chosen to test the HAVING will not be the ABA group rather than the AAA group?  Moving the same condition to the WHERE clause seems more intuitive.

Comment: @Koen No, that's not what is happening, and you are reading my query incorrectly.  I bring each series of three consecutive years into single records, then check if all three years happen to all have A ratings.  The `GROUP BY` is _only_ there to sum up the number of consecutive A ratings, and it serves no other purpose.

Comment: @Tim: Appreciate your help! Your query works perfectly fine and has fetched the desired result.